# How to choose among CSS modular methods like BEM, OOCSS, AMCSS, SMACSS, SUITCSS and others?

Tags: css, oocss, bem, smacss

The is a lot of modular solutions for CSS. I listed some in the subject but probably there have been more already. How do you choose which one to use for your new project? Is there any comparison?

Answer (score 7):

A lot of them are designed so you can choose the parts you like, leave the parts you don't. If you are working with a team, see what everyone is comfortable with. A popular mix is building components or "objects" from an OOCSS point of view, oragnizing files per SMACSS, and using BEM naming conventions.